# How to select count of number of employees reporting to senior manager?

Tags: mysql

I have a table - **userinfo** where i'm having some attributes **userid,firstname,lastname,EmployeeId,ReportTo**

**ReportTo** referes to manager that is **userid** in table **userinfo**

My question is how to get number of **employees** who report to particular manager

here is the sample type of output i need to get

```
userid         FLname         ReportTo     NumberOfEmployees

2               abc [123]       46          456
3               xyz [323]       2           102
4               aaa [525]       3           34
```

i have tried this query

```
select userid,concat(Firstname,' ',Lastname,' ','[',EmployeeId,']')as FLname,ReportTo,(select count(*) from userinfo where ReportTo=userid)as NumberOfEmployees from userinfo where  ReportTo=3
```

i don't know much about count(*) so how can i get the results ?

Comment: Provide some sample table data also.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

any ways i solved the problem
i have tried this query it works fine

```
select ui.userid,concat(ui.Firstname,' ',ui.Lastname,' ','[',ui.EmployeeId,']')as FLname,ReportTo,(select count(*) from userinfo ui1 where ui1.ReportTo=ui.userid)as NumberOfEmployees from userinfo ui where  ReportTo=3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this.

```
SELECT userid,concat(Firstname,' ',Lastname,' ','[',EmployeeId,']')as FLname,count(reportTo) as NumberOfEmployee
FROM userinfo 
 WHERE ReportTo=3
group by userid,firstname,lastname,EmployeeID
```

Comment: `Column 'userinfo.EmployeeId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
` its showing this error

Comment: i tried your query but its showing all the employees whose under that particular manager but i have tried in some other way i have posted my answer see that once it works perfectly fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 select ReportTo,(Select concat(Firstname,' ',Lastname,' ','[',EmployeeId,']') from userinfo Where userid = 5) As FLname,count(*) As NumOfEmployees from userinfo Where ReportTo = 5 Group By ReportTo
```